# Laravel Stripe (no Cashier) Multiple webhooks

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I'm using Laravel with Stripe (directly stripe/stripe-php, not Cashier).
In the config there is this content:

```
'stripe' => [
    'model' => App\User::class,
    'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
    'webhook' => [
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET'),
        'tolerance' => env('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_TOLERANCE', 300),
    ],
],
```

What is the point of having only one webhook secret available there?

```
'secret' => env('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET'),
```

Most apps will have multiple webhook listeners. In my case I added in the env file several different webhook secrets, one for each, actually, but I left the config/service with the first one:

```
.env
STRIPE_WHS_CHECKOUT_OK=whsec_Z***Rp
STRIPE_WHS_PAYMENT_FAIL=whsec_M***g7

config/services.php
'secret' => env('STRIPE_WHS_CHECKOUT_OK'),
```

I tried to do some research on Laravel docs, but not much info about this, anyone can shed some light?
Not that the app is broken, it works as explained, but just curious

Comment: What do mean by `Most apps will have multiple webhook listeners` - You should only need 1 webhook that listens to different events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you should only use one endpoint that receives several events. You can control what type of event you want to see from your dashboard:

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#event-types

Comment: ah got it, thanks! Because in my current setup I have one entry point per single event, and in Stripe I created one webhook for each event, that's not very scalable is it...

Comment: Good thing that helps you. Please approve my answer so it can help others as well 